# No data extracted from MySQL database while running my JSP page

Tags: mysql, jsp

JSP and sql experts I have  a brief problem that is nudging my head. I'm a newbie to JSP and database access.
I created a mysql database and successfully ran it via the command line using Java program code compilation.
 However when I try to extract data from the database using JSP page all i receive is an empty or  blank html table with four columns of EMP ID; Age; First Name; Last Name.
The problems is why is it that no data is displayed in the html page from the database ?
 I'm suspicious one of the root causes may be  that produces an error line message, yet when I format it to  I don't get any more error messages. 
Please assist.

Below is the MySQL database:

```
database - 'EMP'.  
table -  'Employees'.  
Columns; id; age; first; last.  
data;   100; 28; Zaid; Khan.      
password - 'password'
```

Below is the FirstExample.jsp code.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*" %>  
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>  

<html>
<head>
    <title>SELECT operation</title>
</head>
<body>
<sql : setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP"
     user="root" password="password"/>

<sql : query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
 SELECT * from Employees;
</sql : query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here are the file and class paths:**

```
JSP page: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\jsp pages\RegName.jsp  

CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar 

JAVA_HOME: C:\glassfish3\jdk  

Path: C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm receiving an empty html/jsp table with no data extracted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838507/im-receiving-an-empty-html-jsp-table-with-no-data-extracted)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*" %>  
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>  

<html>
<head>
    <title>SELECT operation</title>
</head>
<body>
<sql : setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP"
     user="root" password="password"/>

<sql : query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
 SELECT * from Employees;
</sql : query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
</tr>`enter code here`
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```